# Guidance in buying a tenor saxophone

Tags: instruments, saxophone

I want to buy a tenor saxophone.

The thing is that I used to play a bit on a very old (& nasty) one and now I want to make an upgrade.
I was thinking of buying it from the [thoman superstore](http://www.thomann.de/gb/tenor_saxophones.html) (btw, I live in europe, so that's like my single option).

I'm not a professional (actually kind of a newbie at sax), I just want to play for myself and with my friends, so I don't really want to make a big investment. My desired price would be somewhere below 700€.
Ok, now for the actual question(s) :

- Should I trust smaller brands like "[thomann](http://www.thomann.de/gb/thomann_tts150.htm)" or "[startone](http://www.thomann.de/gb/startone_sts75_tenorsaxophon.htm)"?
- Are there any good tips for buying a tenor sax?

Comment: The reputable manufacturers for beginner/intermediate saxophones are companies like Selmer, Yamaha, Jupiter. "Thomann" or "Startone" that you mention are likely to be made-in-China garbage that most music stores will not be able to repair for you if something goes wrong. If Thomann themselves have a repair shop and they'll support your purchase, that would change my mind, but otherwise, find the shop that will be supporting your instrument, and ask them what their beginner/intermediate saxophone is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I picked up an excellent second hand one for £200, so I would suggest looking in pawn shops and second hand shops as well as new.

Things to look for in a 2nd hand one:

- all the keys work smoothly
- each note is in tune
- no dents or dings
- consistent tone across the full range

That's about it really - I tried 3 different tenor saxophones, which were all fine, before settling on the one I picked up. My decision was on quality of finish - I got the one that looked newest.